# How to fit image to pictureBox?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, picturebox

I'm working with C# OpenCVSharp.
I have a problem with displaying an image in pictureBox properly.

I'm using an Industrial Camera to this and have no idea how to fit the captured image in pictureBox.

When I use programm: IC Capture (producer programm) to watch what the Camera shows I can see that all is right.

When I'm using pictureBox and try all of the SizeModes - it doesn't work how I want.

There's some screens from my programm how it looks:

[image](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/359hf9k/8)

Have You any ideas how to solve it?

EDIT:
There's my code:

```
...

    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread captureThread;
    CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(2);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void onlineCAM()
    {

            while (true)
            {
                IplImage img = cap.QueryFrame();
                img = img.Clone();

                Bitmap bm = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(img);

                this.pictureBox3.Image = bm;
                storage.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.captureThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => this.onlineCAM()));
        this.captureThread.Start();
    }
}
...
```

I'm setting SizeMode in PictureBox3 Properties and it doesn't work...

Comment: It is strange behaviour, strech should work. From MSDN "Using the StretchImage value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit the PictureBox". The problem must lay somewhere else. Are you sure the image you assigned to Image property of the picture box is the valid one?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that my code is OK, because I tested it with Internet Camera and Stretch works.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Edited my post, I think maybe there's some file (Camera Driver) where I can change default properties of image viewing (eg. Zoom) of the Camera or something like that.